# Does setting an optional instance to nil call deinit (if implemented)?

Tags: swift, null, option-type, deinit

This might be a crazy question, but its something that has been bugging me this week. In Swift if you have an optional instance of a class does setting that optional to nil call deinit (if implemented) or do any cleanup on the instance?

```
// OPTIONAL INSTANCE OF PLANET
var newPlanet: Planet? = Planet(name: "Earth", atmosphere: "Oxygen")
if let planet = newPlanet {
    planet.description()
}
newPlanet = nil
```

I am assuming that after setting the pointer to nil that particular instance of Planet is no longer accessible?

Comment: Have you tried it? Just implement `deinit` and add a `println`.

Comment: I did, and it does not get called, well not in playgrounds anyways. I was just wondering what happens in this situation.

Comment: Releasing objects in the Playground does not work reliably. I think that is documented in some release notes. It should work as expected in a compiled project. – Instead of asking if deinit is called or not, it would be more constructive to tell your actual experience, and add the information about the Playground.

Comment: Ah I see, much appreciated. To be fair I neglected to mention the Playground as I did not think it was related, now I see it is, I concede it would have been useful to note.